How can I create a loading screen in Tkinter python?
My application doesn't show the frame. I'm using a system with controllers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter

In my application, I have a function that takes a long time to execute. I want to show a loading screen while it's running. My program is working, but it's not showing the frame "AnimationWindow". This is weird because when I call the frame in other ways it works.
    def anim():
        self.controller.show_frame("AnimationWindow")
        while True:
            if self.l[0]:
                break
            time.sleep(0.01)
    def start_stream(self,data):
        id=self.add_nameFrame()
        self.l=[False]
        threading.Thread(target=my_func,daemon=True).start()
        self.anim()


Are you looking for something like This answer?

thank you, but the answer, unfortunately, did not help

when you run while True then it can blocks all code and it can't display window - because tkinter waits for end of your function to redraw windows  and widgets. You may need root.update() to force tkinter to redraw elements.

other problem can be that tkinter (like many GUIs) doesn't like to run GUI's function in threads. All operations on GUI should be in main thread. And it may need to use queue to send information ffrom other thread to main thread which can use .after(miliseconds, callback) to run loop which can check if there is new information in queue and update window/widgets

Yes, while turned out to be a problem. I used thread and update. If used after, my window is open, but shouldn't.
Thank you!

tkinter (like many GUIs) doesn't update/redraw widgets and windows at once but it waits for end of your function to redraw all changes only once (instead of redrawing window after every change in function). This way it has less work and it doesn't flicking.
And you run while-loop after show_frame() so it waits for end of this loop to show frame.
You may need root.update() to force tkinter to redraw window
def anim(self):
    self.controller.show_frame("AnimationWindow")

    self.update()  # <--- force tkinter to update windows/widgets

    while True:
         # ... code ...

Other method can be .after(milliseconds, callback) to run while-loop in other function - and tkinter will have time to redraw window.
def anim(self):
    self.controller.show_frame("AnimationWindow")
    self.after(1, self.other_function)

def other_function(self):
    while True:
         # ... code ...


And if you want to update widgets when you run while-loop then you may also need to use update
def anim():

    # ... code ...

    while True:
         progressbar.set(new_value)
         self.update()

         # ... code ...


You can also use .after() instead of while-loop
def anim(self):
    self.controller.show_frame("AnimationWindow")
    self.after(1, self.other_function)

def other_function(self):

    # without `while`-loop

    if not self.l[0]:
        self.after(10, self.other_function)  # 10ms = 0.01s
    #else:
    #    close_AnimationWindow()

It can be useful if your splash screen has some button - ie. Cancel - which has to work when you run loop. Normal while-loop would freeze all GUI and button wouldn't react.
